# Castle Dynamic Proxy is it possible to intercept value types?

Tags: castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a problem and can not find answer and any tip if it is possible to intercept value types in C# by Castle dynamic proxy? I want to intercept IDictionary with INotifyChanged interface. I need this to update view when presenter is changing model. Boxing decimal in object only for making interface is not good idea... maybe somebody have idea how to intrcept value types?

Thanks to all answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is not possible. Even if it was it would not work because primitive types are immutable.